Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W. Connect to another WiFi network
I have a fresh raspberry pi zero 2 w with the official os installed(without GUI). I used the default settings in Raspberry Pi Imager to initially connect my Raspberry Pi to Wi-Fi. Now that I moved away from my home I need to connect to another network, but I obviously can’t access my RPi via SSH, because it won’t magically connect to a new Wi-Fi network. One workaround is to reinstall the OS with new Wi-Fi settings. But is it possible to connect to another network without actually reinstalling the entire OS every time I change locations?

With a Keyboard + Monitor, yes - use sudo raspi-config

See: How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm.

@Milliways - that doesn't help with headless setup

@JaromandaX The OP never mentioned headless, indeed your first comment indicates a need for keyboard.

@Milliways - I get it. I was a little vague - I re-read the question, and inferred that the only access OP has is ssh, therefore headless - I should've asked or clarity in my opening comment :p

I was solving same issue as you - first solution was to create hotspot on a mobile phone with same SSID and PW as your home network; second was to use wpa supplicant file  but i have no idea if it still works in recent versions. Third might be to set up same SSID and PW on your router - if that is a option.
